# Does "jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax Helpers in ASP.NET Core" work in Asp.Net Core Razor Pages (New Web Framework from Microsoft)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, unobtrusive-ajax

A download is available in this link [jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/)

That I use in my "**Asp.Net MVC Core 2.0**" applications and eases my work. 
Is this library works in "**Asp.Net Core 2.0 Razor Pages**" so that I can render a "**Partial Page**" in a **<Div id="###"></Div>** element anywhere on the page and Use **Post** and **Get** Ajax calls to my page **handlers**. and If yes Can I **nest** an ajax form in a "Partial Page" to load another Partial Page in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not?

You can use [jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax) as well as render [partial pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages).